# getAll returns nothing? RethinkDB

Tags: python, rethinkdb

Hi I'm trying to read from the DB for different "threads" of messages that are in the DB, but every time I try, I get back an empty array which leads me to think there's something wrong when I'm requesting all threads using the `get_all` command. Is it correct to be requesting from the DB like this? Theres no errors at all so I've been very stumped as it should be returning threads of the messages back.

```
def threads(cls, clinic_id, db={}):
    """Threads

    Returns the unique list of threads in the SMS log

    Arguments:
        clinic_id {uint} -- The unique ID of the clinic
        db {dict} -- Optional DB info

    Returns:
        list
    """

    # Get the info
    dInfo = cls.info(db)

    # Connect to the server
    with connect_with(dInfo['server']) as oCon:

        # Request all threads
        itRes = r \
            .db(dInfo['db']) \
            .table(dInfo['tree']._name) \
            .get_all([clinic_id, r.minval], [clinic_id, r.maxval], index="clinic_number") \
            .pluck(['number']) \
            .default(None) \
            .distinct() \
            .run(oCon)

        # Return the list of numbers
        return [d['number'] for d in itRes]
```

[image: RethinkDB]

Comment: Your question is about `getAll`, but the closest thing in your code is `get_all`. Are these different names for the same method? Or a meaningless typo in the title? Or is this possibly relevant information? (I know nothing about RethinkDB.)

Comment: @abarnert In Javascript, it's used as `getAll` but in python, it's used as `get_all`. Just different syntax for the same method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a secondary index in `clinic_id` called clinic_number, the syntax should probably be:

`.get_all(clinic_id, index="clinic_number")`

unless you want to get a range, where you probably should be using `.between()` instead.

Nor sure what that weird array argument you are passing is supposed to mean.

Note that you NEED a secondary index for that query to work, otherwise you need to use `.filter`, but that forces a table scan which is very non-performant.